# QGIS Layout expression for custom text does not display

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer

In QGIS 3.28, I have template with a simple expression which calculates the sum of a particular attribute (area) and displays this on the map.

Essentially the following:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

project_layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().items()
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', referenced_columns=[])
def summation_of_areas(feature, parent):
    summation_string = ''
    max_col = 20
    for id , layer in project_layers:
        if layer.name() == 'Parcels' or layer.name() == 'parcels':
            try:
                area = str(round(layer.aggregate(QgsAggregateCalculator.Sum, "AREA_HA")[0],1))+str(" ha")
                label =  layer.name().title()
                summation_string = summation_string + "{:<{}} {:>{}} \n"
                summation_string = summation_string.format(str(label),max_col-len(label),str(area),max_col-len(area))
            except Exception as e:
                summation_string = summation_string + "ERROR WITH " +layer.name()
        
    return summation_string
```

The expression itself is simply:

```
summation_of_areas()
```

Which, in the item properties window displays as:

```
[%summation_of_areas()%]
```

When setting the map extent to match the canvas extent, the only way the above expression will display anything at all is if I edit the expression, go to the function editor and click 'Save and Load Functions' then click 'OK'. This is the only way the expression will display anything. I do not have to change anything, just hit that save and load button.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Cool. Other than the omission of chit chat in the post, do you have an idea as to why I am not seeing what I am expecting? Does it have something to do with the way I am declaring the layers?

Comment: I do not use PyQGIS.